# Parameterizing this paraboloid for a triple integral

Tags: parametrization

I am confused about how to find the bounds of integration for the following triple integral.  I seem to have trouble figuring out how to parameterize these curves (like the paraboloid, below).

Also, based on my parameterization, the function that I am integrating over (mass density function, $x^2+y^2$, how does that change once I parameterize it?

$$\int \int \int (x^2+y^2)dxdydz$$ where  $$ \\~\\y^2+z^2 \leq x, \\~\\ 0 \leq x \leq h$$

EDIT:
Would the $y$ bounds go from $0$ to $r cos (\theta)$, and the $z$ bounds go from $0$ to $r sin (\theta)$?  I am pretty sure the $x$ bounds go from $0$ to $h$.  But from here, do I plug in $x=h$ into $x^2$ and $y=rcos(\theta)$ for $y^2$?

Comment: Have you tried cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @SquirtleSquad I provided an edit to what my best guess is.

Comment: Letting $x=x$, $y=rcos(\theta)$, $z=r\sin(\theta)$, your new bound will be $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, $0\leq r \leq \sqrt{x}$, and $0\leq x\leq h$

Comment: In other words, you want to integrate in $x, \theta, r$ not $x,y,z$.

Comment: the integrand function (density) is $x^2+y^2$ (constant in $z$) or $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ ? and where is the paraboloid you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

With $y=r\cos\theta$, $z=r\sin\theta$, Jacobian $r$,
$$
\int_0^h dx \int_{y^2+z^2\le x} dy dz (x^2+y^2)
$$
$$
=
\int_0^h dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}} r dr  
\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta
(x^2+r^2\cos^2\theta)
$$
$$
=
\int_0^h dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}} r dr  
(2\pi x^2+\pi r^2)
$$
$$
=
\int_0^h dx (\frac{\pi}{4}x^2+\pi x^3)
$$
$$
=
\frac{\pi}{12}h^3(1+3h).
$$